# Collection of different types C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have two classes OnlineBoolTag and OnlineDoubleTag. I add these objects to a list and want to get the Value of different types. How to return **Value** property of double or bool?

```
public class OnlineDoubleTag : IOnlineTag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineBoolTag : IOnlineTag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Add objects to a list:

```
var onlinetags = new List<IOnlineTag>();
onlinetags.Add(new OnlineBoolTag { Name = "Bool1", Value = true });
onlinetags.Add(new OnlineDoubleTag { Name = "Float1", Value = 777.22 });

foreach (var tag in onlinetags)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tag.*****Value*****);
}
```

Comment: How is IOnlineTag defined?

Comment: interface IOnlineTag
    {
        public object GetValue()
    }

Comment: Why not implement the GetValue method as `return this.Value` and just call that? What do you need to do with Value in your actual requirement?

Comment: If I implement interface as "return this.Value" I will return the object type. But  I need bool or double.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dynamic` instead of `object`

```
interface IOnlineTag
{
    public dynamic GetValue();
}

public class OnlineDoubleTag : IOnlineTag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    
    public dynamic GetValue()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}

public class OnlineBoolTag : IOnlineTag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    
    public dynamic GetValue()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var onlinetags = new List<IOnlineTag>();
    onlinetags.Add(new OnlineBoolTag { Name = "Bool1", Value = true });
    onlinetags.Add(new OnlineDoubleTag { Name = "Float1", Value = 7777.22 });

    foreach (var tag in onlinetags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tag.GetValue()} {tag.GetValue().GetType()}");
    }
    
    // Value: True Type: System.Boolean
    // Value: 7777.22 Type: System.Double
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dynamic` will help here, as Guy's answer points out. We can simplify this even further though, by defining the property Value to be of type `dynamic` itself. This removes the need to implement the interface for GetValue method. Instead, we can do this:

```
public class OnlineTag 
  {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public dynamic Value {get;set;}
  }

public class Program 
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
     var onlinetags = new List<OnlineTag>();
     onlinetags.Add(new OnlineTag { Name = "Bool1", Value = true });
     onlinetags.Add(new OnlineTag { Name = "Float1", Value = 7777.22 });

     foreach (var tag in onlinetags)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tag.Value} {tag.Value.GetType()}");
        //prints the below
        //True System.Boolean
        //7777,22 System.Double
      }
    }
  }
```

The pitfall with this is that defining Value as dynamic allows you to reassign a value of totally different type later on in your code. For example, the below code will not throw any errors:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{onlinetags[0].Value} {onlinetags[0].Value is bool}"); //prints True True
onlinetags[0].Value = 123M;
Console.WriteLine($"{onlinetags[0].Value} {onlinetags[0].Value.GetType()}"); // prints 123 System.Decimal
```